# How to set up the PostgreSQL tutorial?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on PostgreSQL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-sql-intro.html). I'm running version 9.5.7, so I downloaded the corresponding source code and tried

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Downloads/postgresql-9.5.7/src/tutorial$ make
Makefile:27: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```

However, it's not able to find certain `Makefile`s as shown in the error message above. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You don't really need to "build" them,. The file `basics.source` is essentially a SQL script. You can just run it - or copy and past the statements. The same is true for `advanced.source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by first running

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all
```

After that, the `make` command runs without error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that that there is a different `pg_config` executable in your `PATH` (probably `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_config`), but that installation does not have the extension development environment PGXS installed.

You can either set your `PATH` so that the `pg_config` from your build tree (in `Downloads`) is found first, or you don't use `pg_config` at all and build with

```
make NO_PGXS=1
```